# Limiting what resumes computer from suspend

Tags: 12.04, power-management, suspend

I'm having a ton of trouble getting **Suspend** to work with my laptop. I want to start using Ubuntu but this is a pretty important aspect since I take my laptop with me everywhere. Anyways, I wanted to narrow down the possible problem with my laptop.

What happens is that when I suspend my computer, within seconds, it just boots back up. I have changed `/proc/acpi/wakeup` to where everything is disabled but that did nothing.

Is there a way where I can disable every feature from waking up the laptop except the power button?

Comment: Have you looked at your BIOS?

Comment: Ya. The only thing that BIOS gives an option on is the ability to Enable/Disable USB Wake activity... which I disabled.

Comment: You may have a glitching touchpad. Have you tried disabling it before suspending?

Comment: Ya I've tried disabling the touchpad through bios with no results.

Comment: It would be useful if you can inform us what kind of laptop make/model it is then we can see if this is a known issue for that hardware and/or we can figured out any workarounds or fixes.

Answer (score 0):

How do you suspend? Close the lid? Choose 'Suspend' from the shutdown menu? Call `pm-suspend`?

Have you verified the laptop actually ever properly went into suspend? Easiest indication is the slowly flashing power LED.

The starting point for debugging is to check `dmesg`, `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`.